# Need to Show Error Message when Email is not delivered from SingleEmailMessage

Tags: apex

I have to show an Error Message in VF page when email sent from SendEmail method and it is undelivered, how can we achieve this. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: What do you mean, when it's undelivered?  Do you mean that there was an error sending it, or that the email was rejected at the other end?

Comment: Scenario like, if email address does not exist in other system or deactivated or not delivered ,to be specific In our requirement we are creating a dynamic mail address using Apex and sending email with Send email method based on user requirement. if user created address not exist in outlook email is not delivered successfully , an error message to display in VF page.

Comment: Where does the bounce email go to?  How are you handling the bounce email?  You won't be able to do this on the same page as the page you're using to send the email.